# Change certain controllers inside of yii

Tags: yii

So I want my yii framework application to have its User control handling the login and all of that inside a folder named Backoffice.I haven't tried this yet because I know I will brake the website.

So my question is how to tell yii that the files are located under different directories

Comment: Downvoted for posting twice the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144637/change-location-of-controller-inside-of-yii

Answer (score 0):

You can set a path in config/main file. For example 
`'yiiPath' => dirname (FILE). '/../../framework/yii.php',`
or
        `'import' => array(
            'application.models.',
            'application.components.',
            'application.modules.user.models.',
            'application.components.',
            'application.modules.role.models.',
            'application.modules.profile.models.',
            'packages.solr.',
            'application.modules.registration.models.',
        ),`

Comment: Okay, that did work thank you,but one question is i move for exmaple product controller and go on create it gives me nable to resolve the request "site/error". (C:\Users\steve\Sync\Frameworks\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:286) how can i fix that also :D?

Comment: Check from log files or firebug console, I think something is missing.