# Change location of controller inside of Yii

Tags: yii

I want to change the location of my siteController from protected/controllers to protected/backOffice/controllers.

I have tried to do the following inside of the main config file but it gives me a CExxception error and its doesnt give the much of information

```
Unable to resolve the request "site/error". (C:\Users\steve\Sync\Frameworks\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:286)
```

and i have the following inside of the import

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.backoffice.*',
    ),
```

How i can do this i have found this little helper but still cant understand where i have to put it.
[Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#controllerMap-detail)

Comment: As you included the link you have to put it inside your main.php file under protected/config.

Comment: edited the question forgot to enter my import file form main

Comment: If it is a module then put the controllers in the modules folder but if you want to change the default controller paths then you have to edit core file i guess.

Comment: what do you by mean by core files?

Comment: I mean framework files

Comment: any idea on how to do that?

Comment: You can do it this way as well. Add `'controllerPath' => 'protected/backoffice',` after the `'name'=>'My Web Application',` in your protected/config/main.php. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Okay that worked :D:D now if i want for exmaple booklet controller only to be inside the back office how do i do that?

Comment: Downvoted for posting twice : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142697/change-certain-controllers-inside-of-yii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your config file, it should look like:

```
'controllerPath'=>'protected/backoffice',  <== Add this line
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    //'application.backoffice.*',  <=== You don't need this
),
```

You can achieve the single controller in backoffice by: 
Removing the controllerPath from main.php and add the following:

```
'controllerMap'=>array(
    'booklet'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.backoffice.Booklet', //<== Your controller name
    ),        
),
```